# Regular Expressions Error

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Добрый день. В чем заключается моя ошибка?

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^1/', 'Article.views.basic_one'),
url(r'^2/', 'Article.views.template_two'),
url(r'^3/', 'Article.views.template_three_simple'),
url(r'^articles/all/$', 'Article.views.Articles'),
url(r'^articles/get/(?<Article_id>)\d+/$', 'Article.views.basic_one'),
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю как в питоне, но обычно `(?<` это ретроспективная проверка, только не до конца дописанная. попробуйте `(\?<...`. Ну или две обратные косые, если питон их интерполирует до сборки выражения

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень глубоко разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях, но, если вы хотели использовать именованные группы, то нужно писать `?P<name>`
А у вас P отсутствует.

Соответственно, должно быть так:

```
r'^articles/get/(?P<Aricle_id>)\d+/$'
```

И никогда в вопросах не публикуйте код скриншотом. Только текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в последнем урле, вы не правильно передаете переменную:

```
url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'Article.views.Article')
```